# ReSharper Formatting - put method closing parenthesis on new line

Tags: resharper, resharper-2017

When I declare or call a C# method with multi-line parameters like this:

```
public void DoSomething(
    p1,
    p2,
    p3);
```

Then I would like ReSharper to format that code to like this:

```
public void DoSomething(
    p1,
    p2,
    p3
);
```

Is there a setting that enables this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is only available beginning with `ReSharper 2018.1`.

Those settings are located here:

`Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping`

1. `-> Arrangement of Method Signatures -> Prefer wrap before ")" in declaration`
2. `-> Arrangement of Invocations -> Prefer wrap before ")" in invocation`

Comment: I only see the setting `Prefer wrap before "(" in declaration` with the opening parenthesis, not the closing parenthesis. I'm using version 2017.3.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using 2018.1., thought those settings were in there longer.

Comment: I've updated to 2018.1, and these settings are now available. I've updated your answer to reflect that. Once my update is peer reviewed, I'll accept the answer.